# Power over Ethernet (PoE) power supply requirements clarification, PSE < PD?

Tags: poe

IEEE 802.3at-2009 Table 33-7 shows minimum power supply (PSE) levels that seem to be less than the peak power that the powered device (PD) could draw for Class 1 and 2. Can anyone clarify how these are compatible or where I am misinterpretting the standard?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 802.3 Power over Ethernet Power Requirement Nuance

Background

- Power Supply Equipment (PSE) supplies power to a Powered Device (PD) at a Power Interface (PI) across a link section (cable).
- Pclass defines the average power the PSE needs to supply. (IEEE 802.3at-2009
  Table 33-7)
- Pclass_PD defines the average power the PD is allowed to
  consume. (IEEE 802.3at-2009 Table 33-18)
- Ppeak_PD defines the peak power the PD is allowed to consume. (IEEE 802.3at-2009 Table 33-18)

Nuance

- It isn't always obvious in the standard that Pclass is an
  average value. It can be misleading that for Class 0 and 3 Pclass >
  Ppeak_PD which might lead you to believe Pclass was the peak power
  the PSE would need to supply. Pclass < Ppeak_PD for Class 1 and 2 is
  a sign that this is not correct.
- The internet is flooded with references that get this wrong or hide this nuance.
- https://ethernetalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/WP_EA_Overview8023bt_FINAL.pdf Table 13 helps provide clarity. Attached below.
- PSE peak power (Ppeak_PSE?) is never defined. You must derive it yourself as done in above paper. Note margin has not been added and thus slight Pclass differences vs IEEE 802.3at-2009.

[image]